# Connecting ESP8266 to a 5V DAC

Tags: esp8266, dac

I used an Audio library for the ESP8266 in order to build a WiFi radio player. I bought a DAC to have a good quality sound. The ESP8266 connects to the DAC using a I2S protocol. I wanted to know if I'm connecting it correctly in terms of power supply. Sorry for the poor hand drawing:

[image]

So I have this power supply module that I got with my electronics kit:

[image]

So I connected this to my breadboard, with one side on 5V and the other on 3.3V. The 3.3V is connected to the ESP8266 (MCU) in the drawing. The DAC is connected to the 5V side.

Is this the correct way to wire this?

Comment: Generally not a good idea although it might work. You’ve not told us what dac you are using, so we can’t give a concrete answer.

Comment: Negatives of both supplies must be joined. || Hand drawn diagrams are acceptable if neat - yours could be vastly better if a ruler or equivalent was used.

Comment: @Kartman, what exactly is not a good idea ? I'm using a MAX98357A.

Comment: @Russel McMahon , what exactly does that mean? should I draw a wire between the negative of both sides?

Comment: Since you’ve now told us what dac, we can give a more concise answer. Yes, it will work with 3V or 5V. There’s a zillion examples for connecting these two devices on the interwebs.

Comment: @Kartman in practice the two supplies negative wires should be joined and connected to MCU ground and DAC ground.